# UI5 getting table rowIndex based on Mouse event x and y

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-droppable, sapui5

i have to make a UI where i need to drag Item from List to Table

I followed this [post](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/08/21/how-to-use-drag-and-drop-between-two-sapui5-ui-elements) and made drag and drop and it is working fine. But problem is i need to add to the exact row where user dropped.

How to find the rowIndex from the JQuery [DropEvent](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of making table as droppable, we can make each row as droppable as below

```
var tableId = this.oTable.getId();
$("#"+tableId+" tr").droppable({  
    drop: this.onDroped.bind(this) 
});
```

So we can catch exact row where it is dopped, then we can decide where we can add the droped data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checking items positions one by one helps.

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("idTable");
var items = oTable.getItems();
```

Each item position can be compared with DropEvent's position.

```
item.$().offset();
```